# $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ , why does that imply that $g(x)=\frac {f(x)} x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, definition

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, $0<a<b$ and $\frac {f(a)} a= \frac {f(b)}b$.

Why does that imply we can define a function $g(x)=\frac {f(x)} x$ and what are the uses of this function?

(The context of this question: show that there exists $c\in (a,b) s.t: cf'(c)-f(c)=0$, I already know how to solve this with the above $g$)

Comment: what is the context of the problem? you can define g because $x \neq 0$ on your interval so the quotient is well-defined.

Comment: $g$ is well defined on $[a,b]$ since $0<a<b$ so the denominator never vanishes. The use of $g$ depends on what problem you have

Comment: If $0<a<b$, then you can always define $g(x)=f(x)/x$, no matter if $f$ is differentiable or continuous or anything else...

Comment: $g(x)$ would satisfy $g(a) = g(b)$. A possible use of this function is for example: there exist a  $c\in(a,b)$ s.t. $g'(c) = 0$ ([Rolles theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)) which becomes $[cf'(c)-f(c)]/c^2 = 0$

Comment: @Tyler, I added the context of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $0<a<b$ and $f$ is a real-valued function defined on $[a,b]$ then we are certainly allowed to define the function
$$g(x):={f(x)\over x}\qquad(a\leq x\leq b)\ .$$
I cannot guess the "uses" of this function your author has in mind, but they will become apparent when you read on in your text.