# If $f(a)/a=f(b)/b$ then there exists $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=f(c)/c$.

Tags: calculus

> Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ if $f(a)/a=f(b)/b$ then there exists '$c$ 'in (a,b) such that $f'(c)=f(c)/c$.

Instead of required proof I got the result $f'(c)=f(a)/a=f(b)/b$ which can be proved using Lagrange's mean value theorem and componendo and divido rules... Can any body help me to prove required result?

Comment: Please format your questions using MathJax or latex, so that they are more friendly to read.

Comment: Is $0 < a < b$? Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139337/f-is-continuous-on-a-b-differentiable-on-a-b-why-does-that-imply-th.

Answer (score 5):

We may need more condition on $a,b$: they have same sign. If not, there is a counter example: take $f(x)=1-x^2$ and $a=-1,b=1$. Then $f’(c)=f(c)/c$ leads to $c^2=-1$.

If we add the condition, it follows from the Rolle's theorem applying to $g(x)=f(x)/x$.