# An add-on question on Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, mean-value-theorem

I must demonstrate that there exists $c \in (a,b)$ where $a,b \ne 0$ such that $f'(c)=c\!\cdot\!f(c)$ if the Rolle's theorem's third condition, which is $f(a)=f(b)$, is replaced by $\dfrac{f(a)}{a}=\dfrac {f(b)}{b}$.
Please suggest how I should proceed.

EDIT: Attaching the snap of the question.
(The answer is option c)
EDIT1: The answer key must be incorrect. The obvious answer should be option d) as evident from the counter examples in the answers and comments below.
[image]

Comment: @geetha290krm Exactly where I GOT STUCK. Won't that give $c.f'(c)=f(c)$ in stead of $c.f(c)=f'(c)$?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not in fact answer D) that is correct? See here e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2880608/874549 , also, you might need an assumption on $a$ and $b$, namely that they have the same sign

Comment: In fact, just taking $f(x) = x$ on, say, $[2,4]$ shows that C) cannot be true. We have $\tfrac{f(2)}{2} = 1 = \tfrac{f(4)}{4}$, but we would need a $\xi \in (2,4)$ such that $\xi^2 = 1$ for C) to hold, unless I am misunderstanding something

Comment: A counter-example to A, B, and C is a=2, b=3, f(x)=x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;0<a<b\;$ or $\;a<b<0\;$, we can take into consideration the following function:

$g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R\;$ defined as

$g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}x\;\;$ for any $\;x\in[a,b]\,.$

The function $\;g(x)\;$ satisfies all the hypothesis of Rolle's theorem, hence there exists $\;\xi\in(a,b)\;$ such that $\;g’(\xi)=0\,.$

Since $\;g’(\xi)=\dfrac{\xi f’(\xi)-f(\xi)}{\xi^2}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\xi f’(\xi)=f(\xi)\,.$

It means that actually the correct answer is the option (D).

---

**Addendum :**

If $\;a<0<b\;,\;$ there are functions $\;f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R\;$ continuous on $\,[a,b]\,,\,$ differentiable on $\,(a,b)\,$ such that $\,\dfrac{f(a)}a=\dfrac{f(b)}b\,,\,$ but the option (C) is not satisfied.

For example :

$f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R\;$ defined as

$f(x)=x^2+x-1\;\;$ for any $\;x\in[-1,1]\,.$

This function $\,f(x)\,$ is continuous on $\,[-1,1]\,,\,$ differentiable on $\,(-1,1)\,,\;$ moreover

$\dfrac{f(-1)}{-1}=\dfrac{f(1)}1\;,\;\;$ but

$xf’(x)=2x^2+x>f(x)\;\;$ for any $\;x\in(-1,1)\,.$

Consequently, there does not exist any $\;\xi\in(-1,1)\;$ such that $\;\xi f’(\xi)=f(\xi)\,.$

---

**Another addendum :**

The option (C) cannot be correct, indeed there exists the following counterexample:

$f:[2,3]\to\Bbb R\;\;$ defined as $\;f(x)=x\;$ for any $\,x\in[2,3]\,.$

This function $\,f(x)\,$ is continuous on $\,[2,3]\,,\,$ differentiable on $\,(2,3)\,,\,$ moreover

$\dfrac{f(2)}2=\dfrac{f(3)}3\;\;$ but

$\dfrac{f’(x)}{f(x)}=\dfrac1x<\dfrac12<2<x\;\;$ for any $\,x\in(2,3)\,.$

Consequently, there does not exist any $\;\xi\in(2,3)\;$ such that

$\dfrac{f’(\xi)}{f(\xi)}=\xi\,.$

Answer (score 1):

We have to consider $f(a)=0=f(b)$, additionally

Consider $g(x)=e^{-x^2/2}f(x)$ such that $g(a)=0=g(b)$.
Apply Rolle's theorem on $g(x)$, so $g'(x)=-x e^{-x^2/2} f(x)+e^{-x^2/2} f'(x)=0$ for $x =c, c\in (a,b) \implies f'(c)=cf(c), c\in (a,b)$.

Comment: Just a small doubt. How to proceed in case of $f(a) \ne f(b)$. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: No,$f(a) =f(b) $is necessary part of Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Yes, but I mean to ask sir, what if f(a) and f(b) are unequal, provided f(a) /a = f(b) /b in the add on version of Rolle's theorem wherein the third condition of f(a)=f(b) has been actually replaced as this question requires.